# Does there exist $T \in L(\Bbb R^6) \setminus \{0\}$ such that $\text {Im}\ (T) = \text {Ker}\ (T)\ $?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, examples-counterexamples

> Does there exist $T \in L(\Bbb R^6) \setminus \{0\}$ such that $\text {Im}\ (T) = \text {Ker}\ (T)\ $?

**My attempt** $:$ I take $T : \Bbb R^6 \longrightarrow \Bbb R^6$ defined by $T(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6) = (x_4,x_5,x_6,0,0,0),\ $ $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6) \in \Bbb R^6.$ Then indeed we have $\text {Im}\ (T) = \text {Ker}\ (T).$ Am I right? Please check it.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Yes, it is perfect.

Comment: Yeah this is correct.

Comment: Why do you think that it might be wrong?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The answer key to this question has wrongly pointed out that it is wrong. That's why I posted it here to confirm my approach. Thanks.